# Parse xml via NSString with NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

I try to parse an NSString in XML format using the NSXMLParser class but I unable to analyze it all.
it just displays the elements of the first tag (element)
When I parse the content inside an XML file i get all elements.

```
#import "Parser.h"
#import "DeviceConfig.h"

@implementation Parser

@synthesize curElement;
@synthesize value;
@synthesize defaultValue;

-(id) initWithXMLData: (NSString*) data {
    if(self == [super init]) {
        xmlData = data;
        NSData* xmlNSData = [xmlData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        cameraOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlNSData];
        [parser setDelegate: self];
        [parser parse];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary*) getCameraOptions {
    return cameraOptions;
}

- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser*) parser didStartElement:(nonnull NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(nullable NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(nullable NSString *)qName attributes:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,NSString *> *)attributeDict {
    NSLog(@"started element : %@", elementName);
}

- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser*) parser didEndElement:(nonnull NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(nullable NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(nullable NSString *)qName {
    NSLog(@"ended element : %@", elementName);
}

- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser*) parser foundCharacters:(nonnull NSString *)string {

}

@end
```

main

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Parser* p = [[Parser alloc] initWithXMLData:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><flash></flash><torch></torch>"];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without sample XML, it's hard to guess what it **should** produce.  Do you see anything interesting if you implement `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError`?

Comment: I get this error : 
error : Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={NSXMLParserErrorColumn=54, NSXMLParserErrorLineNumber=1, NSXMLParserErrorMessage=Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: so, where is your _actual_ parser? I see a totally blank implementation in your OP only...

Comment: I found the solution, in my xml string I forgot to add a root element :D
Thank you my friend for helping me.